# Why is it "roof of mouth" and not "ceiling of mouth"?

Tags: word-usage

I am actually a native English speaker but I thought this question would be better on ELL than ELU.

My house has a roof outside with free space above it. It also has ceilings inside with free space below them. However, the *roof of my mouth* is inside, like a ceiling, and has free space below it, also like a ceiling. Why don't we call it the *ceiling of the mouth*?

Answer (score 1):

Which is more your like your mouth?

A housetop or a [cave](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/roof)?

Comment: wow, so caves have roofs! I never knew.  But now how can I use my mnemonic about stalactites (ceiling) and stalagmites (ground)?? .... My troglodite veltanschauung is kaput!

Comment: oh, well, it should have been "floor" anyway, not "ground", because in a cave, the ground is overhead.  So I'll have to call them stalartites (Roof) and stalafmites (Floor)

Comment: Waaaaay off topic, but: Stalag**tites** hang down & so do "teats" (rough translation from German). Can't have  your Weltanschauung go kaputt, can we? ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If you go up into the attic and look up at the roof, it is still the roof. The ceiling is actually the top surface of a room, usually lower than the roof in most modern or multi story buildings.

The *roof* is the top structure of a house, same as the top portion of your mouth.

Answer (score -1):

Why is the side of the hand opposite the back called the palm and not the front? It's just idiomatic usage.

Comment: I realise you are a new user and can't comment yet but please refrain from posting comments as answers until you earn the privilege.